# Erro ao subir site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, symfony-2, symfony

Pessoal acabei de subir um site meu feito no Laravel 5.2 com pho 5.6 localmente. Subi para uma hospedagem compartilhada na Locaweb que tenho. Configurei o PHP 5.6 de forma correta e subi o site ai esta me dando a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/storage/b/71/41/supra/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 351

Este é o primeiro site que subo na versão 5.2 do Laravel. Na versão 5.1 nunca tive nenhum problema.
Veja se vocês conseguem me ajudar. Muito Obrigado

Comment: **Mbstring PHP Extension**. Essa extensão está habilitada no server ? Locaweb... tem que duvidar de tudo.

Comment: @PeterParker Olha esta assim no phpinfo de la. Additional .ini files parsed:  /etc/php56.d/20-mbstring.ini entre outras bibliotecas nesta linha. Acredito que esteja habilitada sim.

Comment: Tem o site aí ?

Comment: A melhor opção talvez seja trocar de hospedagem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa função que está dando erro **não é a MBSTRING do PHP**.

Perceba que há um namespace antes:

```
Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\icon_strpos()
```

Essa é  uma biblioteca do `Symfony` que provê  funções caso  a mesma não exista no sistema.

Talvez isso pode ser um erro de versão que foi instalada dessa biblioteca.

Você pode tentar rodar `composer update` antes de enviar os arquivos para o servidor.

Outro problema que percebi para quem está tendo esse problema é quando o `php5-mbstring` não está instalado.

Veja como proceder a instalação:

```
 sudo yum install php55-mbstring
```

Fonte: [Laravel: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\mb_convert_variables()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971812/laravel-call-to-undefined-function-symfony-component-console-mb-convert-variabl)

Caso seja um servidor compartilhado, contate o suporte técnico para ver se eles podem ativar essa extensão (dependendo da alteração,  mesmo sendo servidor compartilhado, eles alteram).

Comment: olha eu fiz isto. Inclusive por via das duvidas eu removi a pasta Vendor e e enviei novamente e o erro persiste. Ja pesquisei e não encontrei nada. Liguei no suporte da Locaweb e eles disseram que não dão suporte em programação.

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo dá uma pesquisada na internet para ver se você consegue ativar a extensão mbstring via `htaccess`... Não sei, mas pode ajudar!

Comment: O suporte da Locaweb resolveu o problema. O servidor php estava com problemas e reinstalaram ele ai deu certinho. Muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: O -1 deve ter um bom motivo, né, já que a resposta foi aceita